# How to target different Android architectures?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, apk

I am currently using the OpenCV (OpenCV4Android) library which does not use the NDK (there is no C or C++ code). However, there are .so files for armeabi, armeabi-v7a, mips, and x86. If I include all of these in the project, the app size is 30mb, whereas if I include only 1, the app size is only 9mb. If I try to run the app on a device that doesn't have that device's architecture's .so file included, it crashes, whereas if I have it's .so file included, it works.

Therefore, I am wanting to release multiple APKs to different device architectures to reduce the file sizes. From what I've seen, this can only be done in the Application.mk file, but my library does not have one. Is there another way to target different Android architectures?

Comment: If there are .so files, then it's using the NDK.

Comment: Is it possible, at (or after?) install time, to indicate that a separate APK must be installed? Then you could break your app into five, a core APK and four architecture-specific ones, and after the core app is installed it would detect the arch and install the necessary additional APK. I believe that if they are using the same package name they can work together as a unit, but I've never tried anything like this. Apologies if I'm way off base.

Comment: @immibis I assume the so files are from a precompiled library( OpenCV4Android ) and in this application project, the developer is not using NDK to build the so files.

Answer (score 18):

> I am currently using the OpenCV (OpenCV4Android) library which does not use the NDK (there is no C or C++ code). However, there are .so files for armeabi, armeabi-v7a, mips, and x86.

As immibis put it, if there are `.so` files, then it is using the NDK.

> If I try to run the app on a device that doesn't have that device's architecture's .so file included, it crashes, whereas if I have it's .so file included, it works.

That depends upon the device. Many x86 devices have `libhoudini`, which can run ARM NDK binaries, albeit more slowly than they would run native x86 binaries. Similarly, an `armeabi-v7` device can run `armeabi` NDK binaries, though perhaps more slowly, particularly if floating-point processing is used.

> Therefore, I am wanting to release multiple APKs to different device architectures to reduce the file sizes. From what I've seen, this can only be done in the Application.mk file, but my library does not have one.

The `Application.mk` file only controls what gets compiled, not what gets distributed.

> Is there another way to target different Android architectures?

Use Gradle for Android, perhaps in conjunction with Android Studio, and [the `abi` split](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits):

```
android {
  ...
  splits {
    abi {
      enable true
      reset()
      include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips'
      universalApk true
    }
  }
}
```

The `abi` closure in the `splits` closure:

- opts into having different APK files per CPU architecture
- sets up a whitelist of the architectures that you want
- also requests a "universal APK" that contains all of the architectures, for use with distribution channels that do not support separate APKs by architecture

The result of your build will be separate APKs by CPU architecture, plus the universal one.

Comment: That is great news to hear, so if I use this method am I able to deploy multiple APKs to the store for one app to target multiple architectures?

Comment: ...using a single "include" for each APK, such as include 'armeabi-v7a'?

Comment: @AggieDev: You would list in the `include` statement the architectures you want and skip the ones that you don't want (e.g., `mips`, probably). You will get one APK per architecture. In terms of distribution on the Play Store, my understanding is that it supports separate APKs per architecture, though I haven't tried it personally.

Comment: you'll have to have different version codes for each of these architectures as Kiran said, and upload your APKs to the developer console in "advanced mode". Here is a gist that may help you handling version codes properly from gradle: https://gist.github.com/ph0b/69586260bc20c58136ef

Answer (score 10):

Each apk for the application should have unique version code specified by `android:versionCode`. Some x86 devices can run ARMv7 binaries. So, to avoid a case of ARMv7 apk getting downloaded/used in x86 device ( and similar scenarios for other architectures ), **you should order the version codes**. For e.g., order the version codes so that, the x86 APK has a higher version code than ARMv7. More on versioning at this [link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/11/12/how-to-publish-your-apps-on-google-play-for-x86-based-android-devices-using).

A `build.gradle` sample for creating unique version coded apks for each architecture of your choice is shared by ph0b at [github](https://gist.github.com/ph0b/69586260bc20c58136ef). Copying the same below.

```
splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a' //select ABIs to build APKs for
            universalApk true //generate an additional APK that contains all the ABIs
        }
    }

    // map for the version code
    project.ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi': 1, 'armeabi-v7a': 2, 'arm64-v8a': 3, 'mips': 5, 'mips64': 6, 'x86': 8, 'x86_64': 9]

    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        // assign different version code for each output
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.abiFilter, 0) * 1000000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
```

*Suggestion: Android multiple apk support [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html)  suggests  **to not use multiple apks** if apk size is less then 50mb.*

> You should generally use multiple APKs to support different device
>   configurations only when your APK is too large (greater than 50MB) due
>   to the alternative resources needed for different device
>   configurations. Using a single APK to support different configurations
>   is always the best practice, because it makes the path for application
>   updates simple and clear for users (and also makes your life simpler
>   by avoiding development and publishing complexity).

Comment: The documentation updated the suggested size from 50mb to 100mb. "You should generally use multiple APKs to support different device configurations only when your APK is too large (greater than 100MB)"

Comment: `Could not get unknown property 'abiFilter' for`

Answer (score 3):

I do not recommend to use this pattern to build your Build number.
ARCH - BUILD, because if one day you want to come back to one APK, you will have to increase your versionCode a lot. instead you can follow this pattern:
 BUILD - ARCH

```
android.defaultConfig.versionCode * 100 + project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI), 0)
```

exemple for build 74 the build number will be:
    7402 - armeabi-v7a
    7408 - x86