# Facebook Fresco and Sinch Android

Tags: android, facebook, native, sinch, fresco

I'm working on a big project and I'm using the Fresco library from Android and also the Sinch Library for Making VoIP calls... I know these two items are not related in any way as their function are way too different, but I found some kind of bug/error. Which is the following:

The Sinch Library uses eabi for arm, armv7 and x86 architectures for working and making the VoIP calls, and Fresco uses the same three plus the x64 ones. 
When Android tries to load the Sinch library it says `UnsatisfiedLinkError` because it looks up for the .so file on the other folders rather on the three mentioned before...

My question here is... Is there a way to force loading a Native Library from a specified path? Because, my whole project uses Fresco, and removing this library is not an easy task....

Thanks!!!

Comment: What version of Sinch are you using?

Comment: @cjensen 3.7.1 the Latest One.

Answer (score 0):

We are working on x64, but for now don't build for x64 it will work on all platforms anyway

Comment: how can I prevent AndroidStudio from building for x64?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100291/how-to-target-different-android-architectures