# application with zebra jar failed to build on non zebra device with INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner, failed-installation

I have developed an application that runs on a zebra TC70.
The main reason for this is that this device has a built-in 2D barcode scanner.

Now I want to also publish the same app in the app store without the zebra requirement. I have built in a check that checks if the device is a zebra device or not (as described [here](http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/4-0/guide/programming_practices/) by Zebra)

Now when I build this app on a doogee s60, this works without a problem.
The app uses the camera instead of the barcode scanner.
When I want to install in on my Sony Xperia XZ Premiumn, I get the following error in android studio
[image]

Now I am not really familiar with "ABIS" in android.
I tried some googeling and this gave me hints to split APKs per CPU model but I don't get that working.

The end goal is that I can get this app working on "every" android device without having to copy all my code into a second project without the zebra jar.

**Android manifest**

- Min SDK: 16
- Target SDK: 19
- Zebra device I have run Android 4.4 or android 5.1
- uses-permission android:name="com.symbol.emdk.permission.EMDK"

**build.grade (app)**

- provided fileTree(include: ['com.symbol.emdk.jar'], dir: 'libs') // this needs to be provided as else the app won't build

**End status:**

- TC70: app is working with the built-in scanner
- Doogee S60: app is working with the camera
- Sony Xperia XZ Premium: app fails to build with error.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I believe the 'ABIS' refers to the binary interface.  When you run native code on a processor/platform it has to adhere to the binary interface spec.  Do a search/verification on what I'm asserting here - it might be as simple as adding an additional library (maybe in the form of a static library, etc.) but you'll need to reach out to the Xperia community no doubt.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100291/how-to-target-different-android-architectures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer.

Apparently it was just one specific library.

I replaced:

```
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
```

by:

```
compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'
```

and this fixed my issue. It was not related to the zebra library.
Also: `implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5' //Works.`

Thanks to "sweisgerber.dev" in this post [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS error on Android 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46094281/install-failed-no-matching-abis-error-on-android-8) as it fixed the issue